# error: package org.apache.kafka.clients.producer does not exist

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I am new to kafka, and while i am trying to run my Producer.java file, I am getting error :package org.apache.kafka.clients.producer does not exist, though i have added the dependency in pom.xml file too. Can't figure out the reason behind this error.

[image]

Following is the dependency i have added in pom.xml.

```
<build>
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: How are you running the code? By default, maven doesn't put dependencies in the JAR

Comment: I had run the code in VSCode before, wasn't working there. But tried with Intellij IDEA and there it worked perfectly fine. So figured out that in VSCode it doesn't add external libraries automatically.

Comment: If you used the Maven vscode plugin along with the maven-exec-plugin, it shouldn't matter what IDE you use because Maven would be responsible for starting the application

Comment: Okay! I would try this. Thank you.